# why is sass not producing a minified css in my visual studio 2012?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, sass, workbench

I have checked the option if I want to have a min.css in my scss file from the settings of Work Bench. Still, I don't have any min.css after I save my scss file.

and also.. i don't have the double pane(one for the scss and one for the css) when I'm editing..

Please help. thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to use Compass to compile your SASS

Comment: @AleshaOleg I'm sorry, i am only a beginner using sass in visual studio, may i know how to use it?

Comment: oh ok. You need to install this app (http://compass-style.org). And there is a nice guide how to use compass (http://compass-style.org/install). If you will have any problems with compiling, write here to me or I will help you with this. Because in Windows, you may have a lot of problems with this:)

Comment: forgot a one moment, to install Ruby you can use RubyInstaller.

Comment: May be you not possible to pay for Compass, because your'e just beginner, in this case try Scout app (http://mhs.github.io/scout-app) it's more friendly!

Comment: @AleshaOleg should i have to install ruby if my team is running c# in visual studio?

Comment: I would recommend trying SassyStudio https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d extension for Visual Studio.  It's nice and simple.

Comment: @ColinBacon does it support double pane(one for the scss and one for the css) while I'm editing? thanks!

Comment: @xawi I don't think it does no.

Comment: @ColinBacon why is that when i disable the workbench and install the sassy studio, I cannot add scss file anymore? thanks for ur help!